# Get params from Ajax Call in controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, grails

my ajax call is passing following data:

```
var quoteParams ={check:true,startDate:date}
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "check/save",
        data: {orderForm : gatherOrderDetails(), quoteForm : quoteParams } ,      // GatherORderDetails will get all the form input values from a form


        success: function(msg) {
            alert(msg.d);
        },
        error: function(msg) {
        alert('error');
        }

    });
```

So in my controller i want to get the 'orderform' and ' quoteForm' as object of class.the class are **Class orderssForm and Class quotesForm**

```
def save(ordersForm orderForm,quotesForm quoteForm){
//now i need to save all the details obtained from 'orderform' and 'quoteform' after procerssing them in database.

}
```

But i get error that the params is invalid.

Comment: Just changed it .

Comment: What are the values ​​of the data you pass through ajax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define your save action like this:

```
def save() {
    // do stuff with orderForm
    params.orderForm

    // do stuff with quoteForm
    params.quoteForm 
}
```

Also take a look at [data binding](http://docs.grails.org/3.1.1/guide/single.html#dataBinding) which can massively simplify the persistence side of things.

Not sure what your javascript gatherOrderDetails() function is doing but if you just need to submit all form elements you can use [serialize](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) e.g.

```
var data = $('form').serialize();
```

Comment: I just used the the param and then made it the instace of the class new object

Answer (score 0):

I'd say, you should access that via `request.JSON`:

```
def save() {
    def json = request.JSON
    doSomething json.orderForm
    doSomethingElse json.quoteForm 
}
```